# How to connect two computers on the same network using python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

This is the server side program

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9077
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection accepted from " + repr(addr[1]))
    c.send("Thank you for connecting")
    c.close()
```

This is the client program

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9077
s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
```

When i run these two programs on the **same computer, it works perfectly.**
But when i run the client and server programs in **two different computers on the same network, the program doesn't work.**

Can anyone please tell me how to send message from one computer to another on the same network.

This is the first time i'm doing any network programming. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting from the client to the client's computer, or well attempting to, because you are using the `client`'s hostname rather than the `servers` hostname/ip address.

So, to fix this change the line `s.connect((host, port))` so that the `host` points to the `servers` ip address instead of the `client`'s `hostname`.

You can find this by looking at your network settings on the server and doing the following:

```
host = "the ip found from the server's network settings"
```

Answer (score 0):

host must be edited to the server's ip if the server is not the same computer.